# correlation between factors

Tags: correlation, spss, likert

I am new to statistics and SPSS. I have a questionerre having 30 likert scaled questions, and 5 factors each having 5 or 6 questions. I made the reliability analysis and no problem is found. all factors have alpha greater than 0.7. Now I want to make the correlation analysis between factors to validate my hypothesises, but I could not find an option in SPSS to assign questions to factors and analyze them. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Alternately, you can use the dropdown menus in SPSS if you're not familiar with writing your own syntax.

Select Transform at the top and then select Compute Variable to access the compute variable screen. The link below shows a labelled screenshot. It is not my content, nor am I affiliated with this university, but I have referred some of my students to it in the past if they were not familiar with SPSS. Basically, just select your variables and move them into the box on the right, adding a plus sign (+) between each to create a sum score. If you want to find the average, put the whole thing in parentheses and divide by the total number of items. You'll need to do this for each subscale.

[Link to website](http://libguides.library.kent.edu/SPSS/ComputeVariables)

Answer (score 1):

There must be better place to post a question about SPSS, but I'll give it a shot.  You can use this type of syntax:
COMPUTE scalea = question1 + question2 +question3 + question4.
COMPUTE scaleb = question5 + question6 +question7 + question8.
Do the same commands to compute scale scores for factors c, d, e, summing the questions that relate to each of your factors.
Then correlate scalea scaleb scalec etc.